# from skimage.viewer.qt.QtCore import Qt ImportError: No module named QtCore

Tags: python, pyqt4, scikit-image

i developed a python script that relies on skimage, QTcore, Pyqt4 using python2.7, my main development was on Ubuntu and i imported and installed all the libraries with no hassle, but now I'm trying to move my development to windows, and I'm struggling with the libraries.

my import list:

```
from skimage.viewer.qt.QtCore import Qt
import operator
import datetime
from PyQt4.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, SIGNAL
import mainwindow as maingui
import gnupg
import os
import createkeyclass as crkey
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox
import threading
```

i installed PyQt4 i can see in it in the C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4 using **PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.7-x64.exe** that i got it from the website.

and installed Skimage library downloaded **scikit-image-master from the github page** and launched the setup.py script using the command

```
python setup.py develop
```

and it showed that it got installed successfully.
and then i did

```
pip install -U -e
```

it showed that it got installed successfully.

the problem that i'm facing now is that when i run the script i get the following missing import:

```
from skimage.viewer.qt.QtCore import Qt
ImportError: No module named QtCore
```

when i comment this library the QTGUI appears fine and the program run which proves that pyqt4 is installed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i fixed this strange error, Skimage.viwer.qt.Qtcore is available on ubuntu but not on windows so by luck i decieded to remove Qtcore and put only Skimage.viwer.qt and it worked.